# Database structure Product MainPicture (Hibernate, Spring Data JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

У меня есть в базе данных сущности Product и Picture.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "products_pictures",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "picture_id"))
    private Set<Picture> pictures = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "pictures")
public class Picture {
  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "pictures")
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
    
    ...
}
```

Отношение @ManyToMany - из-за того, что одно и то же изображение может относиться к разным продуктам.
Я хочу сделать возможным выбор главных изображений для продукта, чтобы эти главные изображения отображались на странице со списком продуктов (например, при помощи карусели). Насколько я понимаю, это можно сделать добавив следующие поля:

1. В сущности Product:

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "products_main_pictures",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "picture_id"))
    private Set<Picture> mainPictures = new ArrayList<>();
```

2. В сущности Picture:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "mainPictures")
    private Set<Product> productsMain = new HashSet<>();
```

Собственно вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я делаю эти отношения? Может есть способ проще? Или вообще одну главную картинку только оставить?
2. Нужно ли добавлять в таблицу pictures или products_main_pictures колонку order типа int, чтобы еще и порядок отображения учитывать? Насколько я понимаю, добавление такой колонки ведет к усложнению операций вставки и удаления из середины.

Comment: Ну вообще "главность" изображения звучит как характеристика картинки, а не какая то новая связь. Я бы видел это как список картинок, где для любой картинки можно указать, главная она или нет. Почему бы тогда просто поле булево в картинку не добавить и не мудрить со связями?

Comment: А если у одного продукта 10 картинок, а главная - одна, то 9 из 10 полей будут false,  то есть 90% лишних данных? Хотя с "главностью" изображения согласен - звучит больше как характеристика.

Comment: Атрибут или нет картинки зависит еще от того, может ли одна картинка быть главной у одного продукта и не главной у другого.

Comment: В моем случае картинка может быть главной у одного и не главной у другого

Comment: Тогда это не атрибут картинки, а атрибут ассоциации или разные типы ассоциаций. Можно реализовать создав две связи -  `mainPictures` и `otherPictures`. И еще вспомогательны метод `getPictures`, который будет возвращать коллекцию со всеми картинками, если нужно.

Comment: Ну да, у меня как раз pictures содержит все картинки, а mainPictures - только главные.

Comment: странно как одна картинка может относиться к разным продуктам. Но если это так, то тогда действительно только через доп таблицу.

Comment: Например, товар внешне один и тот же, а характеристики разные